# VS Code settings.json "end of file expected" when trying to link custom CSS file. No idea why

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get the "Synthwave x Fluoromachine" VS Code theme enabled. Doing this requires you to link a custom CSS file through the "Custom CSS and JS Loader" extension. I have this extension installed, and now need to add

`{ "vscode_custom_css.imports": [ "file:///C:/Users/User/.vscode/extensions/webrender.synthwave-x-fluoromachine-0.0.12/synthwave-x-fluoromachine.css" ] }`
to the end of the VS Code `settings.json` file to link it. My issue is that on line 12 of the full file (I'll show below) the { is showing an error "end of file expected". Looking online through many different places, this seems to mean I need to close it off with another }. But I clearly am, and am very confused on what else I need to do to "end the file". Probably an obvious solution but I've never used JSON before so not sure what to do. So yeah, thanks!

Full `settings.json` File:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Synthwave x Fluoromachine",
    "security.workspace.trust.enabled": false,
    "synthwave84.brightness": 1,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "sweet-vscode-icons",
    "cyber77.brightness": 1,
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {`
    
     }
}

{
    "vscode_custom_css.imports": [
      "file:///C:/Users/User/.vscode/extensions/webrender.synthwave-x-fluoromachine-0.0.12/synthwave-x-fluoromachine.css"
      ]
}
```

Comment: The `settings.json` file should all be one object.  It looks like you made the `{ "vscode_custom_css.imports": ...}` as a separate object outside it.  Put it inside without wrapping it in its own `{}` - i.e., remove those outer braces from that custom setting.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you so much! I'll be sure to remember now it all needs to be one object. I started to learn json a few months ago but didnt get very far and didnt finish, so now that you mention objects I remember how that works again, so thank you for your help and solution!